# problem in using methodology

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I develop a software with Oracle form builder for my final thesis. I want to prepare some of software development document for my final thesis report.

as you know oracle forms blow ver 8.0 is procedural base... I use oracle form 6...

I need to prepare Software Requirement Specification (SRS) and Software design document (SDD) for my report.

the problem is, As we know oracle form is procedural base and it is not Object oriented base I used SSADM methodology for show how my forms are related(draw DFD,CFD,PSPEC)(use cases and flow up events[in uml]) together and their working in generally... right now for SDD I dont know how I should show my low level ,high level desing, and  packages...

Which methodology you offer to me? right now I try to show my my low level ,high level desing by [TOOD](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=584658), but several days ago I find out TOOD is also for Obejct Oriented program,please help me...

One more question we can not use UML for funtional base program?Please with a strong reference plz...

I so worry that my examiner doesn't accept my work...

It is so hard drawing GUI by SSADM :(( plz help me...

I hope you expert people that gathering here can help me...

In my SRS template for UML project before I put : Usecase diagram,and sequence diagram.
and for SDD before in a OO prject I put : Class diagram, package ,component diagram and describe all my Class and than all of function of class (I dont know now how show them for my procedural base project :((  )

Comment: Forms is declarative - not procedural or functional... (although it supports PL/SQL which is procedural, of course)

Comment: jeffrey: thanks so much,so now what is your idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A history lesson.

The closest thing to an official methodology for building Oracle applications is the late Oracle*CASE Method.  I doubt whether anybody has used it in a decade.  Although it did exist as a process, really it was a guide to using Oracle CASE (subsequently Oracle Designer), which itself is a mothballed product.

CASE and Designer used variations on the SSADM product set.  So in the analysis round we defined modules with DFDs.  When it came to the design phase we decorated those definitions  with the Design Editing tool with which we could specify the GUI elements.  But I don't think that diagrammer had ties to any recognised methodology.

I would have included a link to some information about Oracle*CASE method, but it is so old it is pre-Internet (if you can imagine such a thing).

---

If the eTOOD approach allows you to describe Forms by all means use it.  When it comes to GUI I don't think there's much difference between OO and procedural approaches.  Although [Jackson Structured Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Structured_Programming) (or SDM) remains the best way of representing the flow through all the Forms triggers.

My key advice to you is *talk to your examiner*.  Find out what they are expecting.  Saying some random bloke at StackOverflow told you to use a certain methodology is unlikely to improve your grade.

Comment: Oracle*CASE and Designer - that takes me back.  Remember when Designer was going to put Forms programmers out of their jobs because it could generate the forms directly from the ERD?

Comment: @dpbradley - I hear MDA is going to do the same for Java programmers :D